# Typescript decorate class add new method

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I want to add a new method to a decorated class. Everything works well but the compiler complains that the method does not exist, how can I satisfy the compiler?

```
export function decorate( constructor : Function ) {

  constructor.prototype.someMethod = function () {

  }

} 

@decorate
class Test {
  constructor() {
    //Property 'someMethod' does not exist on type 'Test'.
    this.someMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
(<any>this).someMethod();
```

or:

```
this['someMethod']();
```

You can't use interfaces to check that `this` contains method `someMethod()` because you're not in fact implementing the interface so I think these two are the only options...